# Why not getting proper sorted name list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

[image]

*The Array Formula I've used in `H104` is,*

```
{=INDEX($E$104:$E$111, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$104:$F$111, $F$104:$F$111)=1, COUNTIF($E$104:$E$111, "<"&$E$104:$E$111), ""), ROWS($H$103:H103)), IF(COUNTIF($H$103:H103, $F$104:$F$111)=1, 0, 1)*COUNTIF($E$104:$E$111, "<"&$E$104:$E$111), 0))}
```

*The Array Formula in `I104` is,*

```
{=INDEX($F$104:$F$111, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$104:$F$111, $F$104:$F$111)=1, COUNTIF($E$104:$E$111, "<"&$E$104:$E$111), ""), ROWS($I$103:I103)), IF(COUNTIF($I$103:I103, $F$104:$F$111)=1, 0, 1)*COUNTIF($E$104:$E$111, "<"&$E$104:$E$111), 0))}
```

**The Problem:**

- Check in `Column I` for date 
  `02/10/2018` name `Gopal` should be in
  place of `Manoj` & for date 
  `03/23/2018` name `Bablu` should in 
  place of `Ravi`.
- Date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

[image]

**Note,** Check the order of the names for Date `02/10/2018` & `03/23/2018`.

*Suggest me how to rectify the Formula to solve the problem !*

Comment: I suspect the reason its not sorting properly is that your formula works well for numbers, but it cannot deal with text.  If you do not need to use formulas, I would simply use excel's built in sort capabilities and sort on date and then on dame

Comment: @ForwardEd,, thanks for the suggestion but my interest is other than build in Sort command, otherwise I would have do it. ☺

Comment: Have you tried evaluating your formula and see step by step results? That might help to improve it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, yes I tried almost everything,, still busy to fix it ☺

Comment: @MátéJuhász, just check I've solved the issue and it's working properly. ☺

Answer (score 0):

**Since I've fixed the issue, therefore for the benefit of the Community I'm posting the answer.**

[image]

**How it works:**

1. To Rank the Dates write this Formula in Cell `E2` & fill it down.

   `=RANK(F2,$F$2:$F$9,0)+COUNTIF($F$2:F2,F2)-1`
2. Create Rank in Descending order in Cell `J2` write this formula & fill it down.

   `=LARGE($E$2:$E$9,ROWS($E$2:E2))`
3. To reorder Dates in Cell `K2` write this formula & fill down.

   `=SMALL($F$2:$F$9,ROWS(K$2:K2))`
4. To get names in proper order for duplicate Dates write the Formula in Cell `L2` & fill it down.

   `=VLOOKUP(J2,E$2:G$9,3,FALSE)`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*